# Moving the limit sign.

Tags: calculus

I have $f_1(x),f_2(x),g_1(x),g_2(x)$ and I know that:

$$\lim_{x\to x_0}g_1(x)=a\neq0 \\
\lim_{x\to x_0}g_2(x)=b\neq0$$

Please, allow me to write simply $L$ in place of $\lim_{x \to x_0}$; I'm asking myself if I'm allowed to do the last step:

$$L[f_1(x)g_1(x)+f_2(x)g_2(x)]=\\
=L[f_1(x)g_1(x)]+L[f_2(x)g_2(x)]=\\
=L[f_1(x)]L[g_1(x)]+L[f_2(x)]L[g_2(x)]=\\
=aL[f_1(x)]+bL[f_2(x)]=\\
=L[af_1(x)]+L[bf_2(x)]\stackrel{??}{=}\\ 
\stackrel{??}{=}L[af_1(x)+bf_2(x)]
$$

Which theorem allow or deny me to do that? 
Thank you and sorry if the question is a bit unclear or trivial.

I'm asking because sometimes it happened to get a wrong result in calculating a limit because of "moving" the limit sign incorrectly.

Comment: If the limits $L[f_1(x)]$ and $L[f_2(x)]$ both exist then yes.